# To check if a bash script is run as root or a regular user?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have started learning bash scripting. I have a conceptual doubt , How to determine if the script is run as root or a regular user.?

I know the UID if user is 0, But i don't understand how to implement it.? Can anyone explain me how to make it work.? Is it possible to print a message as `"Not a root user"` when the script is run as a regular user?

My script is a simple `hello_world.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello World';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIX shells have the builtin variables `$UID` and `$EUID`. You can also check the return from `id -u`. In every case, the id 0 indicates root.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "This script should be run as root." > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I guess what you want is $EUID, not $UID, because that's how to check if the script is running with root privileges.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer. In practice, I'm not sure how UID could be different from EUID here (or does setuid work on shell scripts on some platforms?).

Comment: The script can be forked off by a parent that changed the effective uid. Although bash by default resets the effective uid to the real uid, unless given the `-p` option, so indeed usually `$EUID = $UID` holds. Other shells like dash do not implement that, however.